# Nobody wants to be me

Tags: riddle, word

I can’t move but I can stop

I can’t climb but I can drop

I can be on but I can’t be off

I can’t be a key but can be a lock

I can beat without a heart

And play without a game

Nobody wants to be me

Can you tell my name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Dead

I can’t move but I can stop

> Can stop dead, but can't move dead

I can’t climb but I can drop

> Can drop dead, but can't climb dead

I can be on but I can’t be off

> Can be dead on, but not dead off

I can’t be a key but can be a lock

> Can be a deadlock but not a deadkey

I can beat without a heart

> Can be a deadbeat but not a deadheart

And play without a game

> Can play dead, but not game dead

Nobody wants to be me

> I wouldn't want to be

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're

> a beat

I can’t move but I can stop

> A beat can stop, but not move

I can’t climb but I can drop

> a [beat drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(music))

I can be on but I can’t be off

> When you turn it off, it's not there anymore. So it's not off, it just,,, isn't.

I can’t be a key but can be a lock

> I guess the beat can't be in a certain key (such as A, Dminor etc). I'm not sure about the lock.

I can beat without a heart

> Well, yes.

And play without a game

> Yes, the beat can play by itself.

Nobody wants to be me

> Nobody want to be beaten.

Can you tell my name?

> Beat

Comment: great effort. Nicely fits many clues but the On Off and Key Lock fit is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are:

> Virus

> I can’t move but I can stop

> virus can’t move by it’s self.

> I can’t climb but I can drop

> virus can’t climb but they certainly can drop if there are nothing **moving** it...

> I can be on but I can’t be off

> I must be on a organism to pass on my DNA or RNA, if not then I will die(not really).

> I can’t be a key but can be a lock

> Virus can’t  be a key but they could lock on you.

> I can beat without a heart

> they do beat but they don’t have heart.

> And play without a game

> ”they play you to death”

> Nobody wants to be me

> A time least I don’t want Tovar’s be a virus...

> Can you tell my name?

> Virus!

Answer (score 2):

Your name might be

> Bullseye

*I can't move but I can stop*

> It can't move as it's on a target that's secured to the wall, but it can stop a dart from flying through the air.

*I can’t climb but I can drop*

> A target can't climb, but it can easily drop, along with its bullseye, if not secured to the wall well enough.

*I can be on but I can’t be off*

> What's the point of a target without a bullseye on it?

*I can’t be a key but can be a lock*

> A bullseye can't be a key, but it could be a lock for your eyes/concentration to throw the dart onto it.

*I can beat without a heart*

> The sound of darts constantly hitting it.

*And play without a game*

> One can "play" darts without a game, as they only play to improve their concentration/precision/skill.

*Nobody wants to be me*

> Image darts flying towards you...

*Can you tell my name?*

> Bullseye!

Comment: Can't move, huh? [Try telling Mark Rober that!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHTizZ_XcUM&vl=en) ;-)

Comment: @Stiv Haha! I've watched *all* of his videos.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution that fits rather well (although admittedly not perfect)

> Music

I can’t move but I can stop

> the music can stop playing

I can’t climb but I can drop

> a common mistake in playing music is to drop a note

I can be on but I can’t be off

> Hey mr DJ, put the music on!

I can’t be a key but can be a lock

> while music is in a key, it is not a key itself. There are music lockets, which for me is close enough to "lock" as a riddle cue.

I can beat without a heart

> Music has a beat

And play without a game

> Music gets played

Nobody wants to be me

> This is the cue that doesn't fit perfectly. Taken literally, it is true but vacuous - people want to be people and not something abstract like music. I could imagine not wanting to be the subject of certain types of song, or maybe being a musician is suggested as a poor career choice, due to bad payment and high stress (although people actually want to be it).

Can you tell my name?

Comment: I like this answer, except there's rot13(ghea gur zhfvp bss) ;)

Comment: I don’t know this, but I am a piano player, isn’t music keys? (Piano keys, and keys such as F# Ab?)